# How do I create a LAN between Windows 11 ARM VM inside Parallels 18 with an external Windows 7/10 machine?

Tags: network, windows, parallels-desktop

I have a Paralells 18 running Windows 11 ARM on an Apple M1 Mac mini that runs a game (Splinter Cell Conviction) perfectly. I want to be able to play this game over LAN with my friend from a different country who has Windows 7/10 on his end. I have spent almost 24 hrs trying to do this and have had no success whatsoever

**Attempt 1 Radmin**

I tried installing Radmin VPN inside my Windows 11 ARM machine and it gives me this error immediately

[image]

I am guessing Radmin VPN doesn't work on ARM versions of Windows. My second guess was to install it on Mac but alas, Mac has no Radmin VPN

**Attempt 2: Hamachi**

**Inside the VM**
From inside the VM, I installed Hamachi but I get a yellow tick mark besides the other person's computer after adding them. Turns out that when you install Hamachi, it is supposed to create a new Adapter in your Network Sharing -> Adapters section but for some reason it doesn't do. I tried manually adding a driver under Device Manager for Hamachi by selecting the hamachi.inf file from the x64 directory but it won't proceed after selecting that inf file

**Outside the VM**

Hamachi simply doesnt work when you install it natively on Mac. It gives this error

[image]

**Attempt 3: Zerotier**

I managed to install Zerotier on the Mac host and my friend's Windows machine. We even managed to ping each other via the command prompt and terminal respectively and we were receiving pings. But once I try host/join game, we cannot see each other. [Turns out Zerotier has a massive issue with LAN](https://zerotier.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/7536695/Problems+With+LAN+Game+Announcements+and+Broadcasts+on+Windows)

**Attempt 4: Gameranger**

Gameranger doesn't support this game so there it goes out of the window

**Attempt 5: PlayHide VPN**

[Tried to install this](https://github.com/crnlc/PlayHide) inside the VM the exe file runs endlessly trying to update but it never succeeds so no luck there.

**Attempt 6: NetOverNet**

[Tried downloading this](https://www.netovernet.com/) on both our machines and again it wont connect or took forever to connect. Judging by the expired SSL certificate I am guessing this one is moot

I give up. Please help, I dont know what else to do anymore

I would super appreciate if someone can help fix this
I have a few questions though
Should I use Shared Network on Parallels or Wi-Fi or something else?
Should I install tools inside the VM or outside the VM?

Answer (score 1):

When faced with network issues like this I find the easiest and most reliable method is a USB to Ethernet adapter that is passed through to the VM. It may be considered “sloppy”, as the network stack in the VM host should be able to manage this, but it does work. By passing through the USB Ethernet adapter the guest VM has complete control of the network, the host network settings become irrelevant and cannot interfere.  It may be necessary for the virtual interfaces to be disconnected or otherwise somehow disabled for the best results since the guest VM may get confused if there is some possible alternate path to follow.

If your internet is not by Ethernet then try Bluetooth or WiFi.  A problem with using wireless on a VM while the host is also wireless is the two can interfere and make things worse for both.  That can be resolved by disabling the host wireless connection.  With the host networking disabled then that will absolutely force the guest VM to direct all network traffic through the USB network adapter (again be that Ethernet, Bluetooth, or whatever) and that way the host isn’t getting in the way.

I recognize this involves a hardware workaround to a software problem, hardware that you may not have and would rather not have to buy, but it’s the path of least resistance for me.

Comment: "A problem with using wireless on a VM while the host is also wireless is the two can interfere and make things worse for both" Not sure I understand this. If the VM just bridges to the host and the host handles the networking, does using wireless on a VM actually make sense at all?

Comment: The goal is not to bridge the VM to the host by wireless but to get the VM connected directly to the internet or other computer, bypassing any bridging or routing the VM host could do.  The interference of having host and VM on a wireless network is having two transmitters on the same frequency band in close proximity and blocking out the WiFi router, Bluetooth hotspot, or whatever the wireless access point might be.  It’s not much different than having two laptops on the same desk with the access point in another room, each laptop is blocking out the other for a good signal.

Comment: A VM doesn‘t have it‘s own hardware, not sure where you see any interference here?

Comment: @nohillside The first sentence of my answer suggests adding a USB Ethernet adapter, that is adding hardware to the VM.  I later point out that if Ethernet is not an option then adding a USB passthrough WiFi or Bluetooth adapter to the VM can give the same ability of bypassing the VM host routing or bridging, but this comes with the risk of interference from the wireless networking that is used by the host.  Presumably the host wireless network hardware is internal, so to prevent interference it may need to be turned off while the VM guest is using a USB wireless network adapter.